# Leverage Table View in iOS as an Intermediate Picker View

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a list of contacts (not from the iOS address book but created within my own app and stored separately) which are shown in a table view. I'm prototyping a messaging app wherein the author can choose which contacts to send the message to. For the same, I would want to utilize the same view controller (that houses the contacts table in the first place) as an intermediate screen, but with radio buttons, etc. included on each row. So that when the user clicks on the relevant radio buttons, those contacts are sent the desired message.

Any indicators on how can I achieve this or proceed forward here? I'm presuming here that I shouldnt be creating a new view controller but should rather reuse the old one instead.

Note that these are contacts created separately and not linked to the iOS address book - which I would probably do later...

Comment: as I understand your question you want to put radio button on each cell. Right?  
Please go through https://github.com/Gagan5278/TableItemSelection-Demo

Comment: Thanks... let me check that out.